# Internet Explorer 8 producing strange CSS bug on :hover

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, web, internet-explorer-8

I'm working on website development, styling a breadcrumb trail with CSS at the moment. However, I came across this strange bug in Internet Explorer 8, and I can't figure out why it's happening. To illustrate, here are some images:

This is what one of the breadcrumbs is supposed to look like when hovered over: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zxSx.png (image taken in Chrome)

In Internet Explorer, this is what it looks like when hovering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrsnT.png

It displays fine before hovering, but as soon as the mouse goes over it, it goes nuts.

I've gone through the CSS code, and the only attributes related to :hover are color, background, overflow, and text-decoration. There is nothing to do with margin, padding, height, etc.

What could possible be causing this?

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="headtitle pull-left">
    <h1 id="pageTitle" class="ms-core-pageTitle">

    CX Team

    </h1>
    <ul class="s4-breadcrumb">
        <li class="s4-breadcrumbRootNode">
            <span class="s4-breadcrumb-arrowcont">
                <img src="/_layouts/images/nodearrow.png" alt="" style="border-width:0px;display:inline-block;padding-top:4px;" />
            </span>
            <a class="s4-breadcrumbRootNode" href="/sites/cc/Pages/index.aspx">Connect</a>
            <ul class="s4-breadcrumbRootNode">
                <li class="s4-breadcrumbNode">
                    <span class="s4-breadcrumb-arrowcont">
                        <img src="/_layouts/images/nodearrow.png" alt="" style="border-width:0px;display:inline-block;padding-top:4px;" />
                    </span>
                    <a class="s4-breadcrumbNode" href="/sites/cc/residential/Pages/index0709-9951.aspx">Residential</a>
                    <ul class="s4-breadcrumbNode">
                        <li class="s4-breadcrumbNode">
                            <span class="s4-breadcrumb-arrowcont">
                                <img src="/_layouts/images/nodearrow.png" alt="" style="border-width:0px;display:inline-block;padding-top:4px;" />
                            </span>
                            <a class="s4-breadcrumbNode" href="/sites/cc/residential/customerexperience/Pages/default.aspx">Customer Experience</a>
                            <ul class="s4-breadcrumbNode">
                                <li class="s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode">
                                    <span class="s4-breadcrumb-arrowcont">
                                        <img src="/_layouts/images/nodearrow.png" alt="" style="border-width:0px;display:inline-block;padding-top:4px;" />
                                    </span>
                                    <a class="s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode" href="/sites/cc/residential/customerexperience/Pages/CX-Team.aspx">CX Team</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I unfortunately don't have control over this; it is created dynamically by Sharepoint (which I am forced to use).

CSS:

```
.s4-breadcrumb a:hover {
    overflow:auto\9;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FF9900', endColorstr='#FF6600');
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#F90,#F60);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#F90),to(#F60));
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#F90,#F60);
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#F90,#F60);
}

.v4master .s4-breadcrumbNode a,
.v4master .s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode a,
.v4master .s4-breadcrumbRootNode a,
.v4master .s4-breadcrumbNode a:hover,
.v4master .s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode a:hover,
.v4master .s4-breadcrumbRootNode a:hover {
    color:white !important;
}

ul.s4-breadcrumb,
ul.s4-breadcrumb ul {
    line-height:normal;
}

ul.s4-breadcrumb a {
    line-height:40px;
}

ul.s4-breadcrumb,
ul.s4-breadcrumb ul {
    margin-bottom:0;
}

ul.s4-breadcrumb .s4-breadcrumb-arrowcont {
    margin-bottom:14px;
}

ul.s4-breadcrumb,
ul.s4-breadcrumb ul {
    margin-left:0;
}

ul.s4-breadcrumb,
ul.s4-breadcrumb ul {
    margin-right:0;
}

ul.s4-breadcrumb,
ul.s4-breadcrumb ul {
    margin-top:0;
}

ul.s4-breadcrumb .s4-breadcrumb-arrowcont {
    margin-top:10px;
}

.s4-breadcrumb a {
    padding-left:5px;
}

.headtitle > ul.s4-breadcrumb {
    padding-left:10px;
}

.headtitle > ul.s4-breadcrumb {
    padding-left:0\9;
}

.s4-breadcrumb {
    padding-left:15px;
}

.s4-breadcrumb a {
    padding-right:5px;
}

.s4-breadcrumb {
    padding-right:15px;
}

.s4-breadcrumb a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant HTML/CSS, this is impossible to debug by looking at screenshots.

Comment: I'll try to guess, try to add `ul li a:hover{margin-bottom:0}`

Comment: Adding ul.s4-breadcrumb a:hover {margin-bottom:0} had this effect: http://i.imgur.com/OjD0RnG.png

Answer (score 0):

I see two things that could cause it: the overflow declaration with an IE9-only hack, and the lack of a declaration that cures the old-IE `hasLayout` bug, which bug acts up if you use CSS filters.

See if this works (I hope that you do have control over the CSS):

```
.s4-breadcrumb a:hover {
    overflow: auto; /* or: hidden */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FF9900', endColorstr='#FF6600');
    zoom: 1; /* cure for the bug */
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#F90,#F60);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#F90),to(#F60));
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#F90,#F60);
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#F90,#F60);
}
```

.
If that doesn't cure it, make a http://jsbinb.com of it. If you give the images a width, height and a border, it doesn't matter that you cannot upload them themselves. That is: if the images in your HTML play a role in this.

Comment: Tried both adding the zoom and commenting out the overflow (as well as setting it to hidden), but neither seemed to have any effect.

Is this what you're looking for? https://gist.github.com/a4849ee75f15967bdd6a

Apologies for the code; Sharepoint is an absolute mess :/

Comment: Or is http://jsbin.com/nicebapu/1 better? It doesn't display perfectly, but should give you an idea.

Comment: I forgot that JSBin and the likes don't function in IE8. Now, I can copy and paste the code into my editor and thus test it in IE8, but you really have to trim the code down to the relevant parts. The code that you included in your question is **missing** essential parts, so that is no good either. Just try that code out for yourself and you'll see.

Comment: What parts is it missing? I would be more than happy to provide my CSS file.

Comment: I don't know that. Just create a page with the two code parts you provided, and see that that doesn't reproduce the problem. It doesn't even form anywhere near a nav menu that you included the images of.

Comment: No, that's no good. You really have to realize that to get answers here, you have to make **live, whole-page but bare-bones demos**. Zipped files, even if they would contain bare-bones demos, mean way too much work for us -- go to the linked page, download the zip file, save it, unpack it, paste it in the editor, and start testing. I for one don't have the time for that.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your assistance thus far. For now, I am just going to set the breadcrumbs bar to display:none; for IE.